# Mobile site off center when jQuery button is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, padding, centering

I have a centering issue that seems to be caused by my animated scroll function. When the button is triggered, the entire site becomes off-centered, with padding on the right side. This only happens with mobile devices / touch screens. If you avoid the button, no issues arise. 
Thanks in advance for your time and help, I'm very stumped!

[Website](http://charissabangs.com/2014/) 
[Screenshot](http://charissabangs.com/2014/img/CBD_screenshot.jpg)

HTML

```
<div id="scroll" onclick="$('#projects').animatescroll();">
    <img src="img/arrow.png" class="image" alt="scroll down" width="65px;"  />
</div>
```

JS

```
(function($){

// defines various easing effects
$.easing['jswing'] = $.easing['swing'];
$.extend( $.easing,
{
        def: 'easeOutQuad',
        swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
                return $.easing[$.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
        },

        easeOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
                return -c *(t/=d)*(t-2) + b;
        },
});

$.fn.animatescroll = function(options) {

    // fetches options
    var opts = $.extend({},$.fn.animatescroll.defaults,options);

    // make sure the callback is a function
    if (typeof opts.onScrollStart == 'function') {
        // brings the scope to the callback
        opts.onScrollStart.call(this);
    }

    if(opts.element == "html,body") {
        // Get the distance of particular id or class from top
        var offset = this.offset().top;

        // Scroll the page to the desired position
        $(opts.element).stop().animate({ scrollTop: offset - opts.padding}, opts.scrollSpeed, opts.easing);
    }
    else {
        // Scroll the element to the desired position
        $(opts.element).stop().animate({ scrollTop: this.offset().top - this.parent().offset().top + this.parent().scrollTop() - opts.padding}, opts.scrollSpeed, opts.easing);
    }

    setTimeout(function() {

        // make sure the callback is a function
        if (typeof opts.onScrollEnd == 'function') {
            // brings the scope to the callback
            opts.onScrollEnd.call(this);
        }
    }, opts.scrollSpeed);
};

// default options
$.fn.animatescroll.defaults = {        
    easing:"swing",
    scrollSpeed:800,
    padding:0,
    element:"html,body"
};   

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed because as soon as you've fixed the problem the question becomes useless for anyone having the same problem later. For instructions on how to improve the question see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: thank you @Juhana, I will add the relevant code my question :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem!

My Fix:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Comment: thanks, though it didn't solve the problem :( But, I should set the body width anyway so I appreciate that suggestion!